# Xamarin Mac Agent Limited

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Estou tentando programar para iOS usando Xamarin, mas já estou começando a ficar frustado. 
Quando abro o Xamarin Studio no MAC, consigo visualizar normalmente o design do meu layout, mas, quando tento visualizar usando Visual Studio no Windows, tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> **Something went wrong**
>
> The iOS Design Mac Agent is not available.
>
> **Actions:**
>
> Start Design Agent

E o ícone de conexão com o MAC está amarelo, com o status de **"LIMITADO"**.

Já não sei mais o que fazer. Pesquisei sobre e não achei nada.

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tentou atualizar os ambientes Windows e Mac para a mesma versão?

Comment: Vou tentar e já volto com a resposta. tks

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio, resolveu! Obrigado mesmo! Me salvou.

Comment: Show vou comentar em resposta então e vc dá um Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro de conexão limitada e não visualização do layout no Visual Studio é relacionado ao fato dos ambientes possuem versões diferentes do Xamarin.

Para corrigir esse problema será necessário atualizar as versões do Xamarin Stable em ambos os ambientes Windows e Mac Ios.